# Something is blocking the call state listener to get called in android over AT commands

Tags: c#, xamarin, server, client, phone-state-listener

I have a strange problem. I'm using an android app as server and a WinForms application as client. They are both communicating over a TCP socket connection. I have following piece code in my App:

```
    public class StateListener : PhoneStateListener
    {
        private readonly MainActivity _activity;

        public StateListener(MainActivity activity)
        {
            _activity = activity;
        }

        public override void OnCallStateChanged(CallState state, string number)
        {
            base.OnCallStateChanged(state, number);
            _activity.UpdateCallState(state, number);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCallState(CallState state, string number)
    {
        PhoneState = state.ToString();
    }
```

And in a thread called from the MainActivity:

```
 while (PhoneState == "Idle") { }
 //some code
```

Now the WinfForms application is making calls over the phone with AT Commands. 
When I trying to make a call directly over the phone (before the connection is established) the state listener works. When I'm doing this over AT commands within the application then the state does not change at all. 
Could this be because of the while loop which blocks the method to be called or could this come from the AT command?

Thank you!